# form style doesn't stay uppercase when pushed to url

Tags: php, forms

I had a search box and scrapped it at one point, in which i had this working at one point but don't remember where i found it), I want to push this post variable and I want it to stay uppercase all the way through to the final page but it goes to lowercase.

Code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['u'])) {
    header ("Location: ./index.php?p=lookup&u=".$_POST['u']);
}
?>
<h2>Driver Search</h2>
<h3>* Are Required Fields</h3>
<div class="content">
<p>

<form id="searchform" method="post" action="">
<div>
*Driver Name: <input type="text" name="u" id="u" size="15" style="text-transform:uppercase;" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>  

</p>
</div>
```

So if i search for the driver "SMOKEU", the url still prints out `index.php?p=lookup&u=smokeu`

Comment: "text-transform:uppercase" is css properties to show text uppercase on screen but it don't deal with input value, input value remains unchanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS style `text-transform: uppercase` only affects what the text *looks like* on the page, not what the value actually *is*.

If you need the value to be all-uppercase, you could just call `strtoupper` on it in your PHP code.

If you're instead more worried about how it looks in the URL that gets created, you'll have to use JavaScript to alter the value as it's typed or just before submission of the form.